# Can I force a .NET XmlDocument instance to release the memory it's holding sooner?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, xamarin.android, xmldocument, xamarin

I have a Mono for Android application that reads XML files using the .NET **XmlDocument** class.  Each document is about 180K.

After parsing each document and creating my own internal data structures, I leave no references to the **XmlDocument** instance, so it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

The problem is, though, that it takes 5-6 seconds before that collection happens, and if I load multiple documents within 5-6 seconds, my app crashes out to the OS with no error messages printed, no exceptions thrown, etc.  It just says that thread 12 exited (I'm not creating any extra threads, so I don't understand why it's thread 12 either -- XmlDocument's thread?).

If I load document 1, then wait 5 seconds, then load document 2, wait 5 seconds then load document 3, etc., then everything is OK.

In that case, during the 5 second wait, I can see the GC kicking in several times and releasing around 1MB of memory in total across 4-5 cycles (some marked EXPLICIT, some marked CONCURRENT).

I also tried adding a call to xmlDocument.RemoveAll() once I am done as suggested by an article I found.  I also added a call to GC.Collect() after that.  It helped slightly, but it still crashes, just somewhat less often.

Any idea how to either increase the available memory or get **XmlDocument** to behave better?

Comment: Could you be not disposing a stream or XmlReader that you are loading the document from, or a stream or XmlWriter that you are saving it with, and hence causing stuff to be added to the finaliser queue, and hence causing more GC promotions?

Comment: If all else fails, try using XDocument. This is a much nicer API, and just maybe it might work better in this scenario.

Comment: Maybe reuse the XmlDocument instances and simply reload them?

Comment: Jon Hanna: I am using the constructor that takes a file path string as an argument, so I am not in control of the stream.

Comment: John Saunders: It's possible that might help, although even calling RemoveAll() on the XmlDocument then doing a GC.Collect() didn't help much, so maybe not.  I think there is some defect in there still.  Perhaps something in how the C# XmlDocument interacts with the Java GC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so much an answer as it is an alternative, but I rewrote my XML parsing code using XmlTextReader and the problem no longer occurs.

Of course XmlTextReader doesn't need to load the whole XML file into memory, which is a huge help to memory usage.

I can load multiple files very quickly one after the other with no crashes now.

The XmlTextReader API was more work to get right, but things seem pretty solid now.